# parse broken json string(response from web api);

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
{{
  "draw": "1",
  "recordsFiltered": 670,
  "recordsTotal": 670,
  "books": []
}}
```

this is the response json data returned from web api.. how can I desirialize it?

here is the asp.net web api method:

```
public JsonResult GetBooks(){
..
return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data = booklist },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
```

The trick make me crazy here, when I make same request in browser it response valid json string:

```
{
  "draw": "1",
  "recordsFiltered": 670,
  "recordsTotal": 670,
  "books": []
}
```

but when I check the content of the response in client debugmode you see an extra scope surroading data.. can someone describe stuation before a joniour developer suicide..

Comment: if the only errors are the extra `{}`, then it's just a simple string operation to strip off the first/last chars of the raw json string.

Comment: it looks that but, we commonly use json for get values data["key"].. right.
So something prevents me do this here..

Comment: it'd only prevent you if you tried to parse the "bad" string. **IF** the {} are the only errors and you remove them, then your example becomes perfectly valid json and can be parsed without issue.